# Is there any way to create Map with enum as key that ensure operator[] is not null?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
enum SomeEnum { first, second }

Map<SomeEnum, String(or any type)> someMap = {
  SomeEnum.first: 'first',
  SomeEnum.second: 'second',
};

String variable = someMap[SomeEnum.first]; <- nullable
```

In codes above, `someMap[SomeEnum.{anything}]` defenitely can't be null because it have all possible SomeEnum as key.

But this causing error because `someMap[SomeEnum.first]` is nullable, can't assign to type `String`

How do I tell flutter that this have all possible enum values and 100% can't be null without using `!` (I don't want to use it because I use this map a lot and this is a little bit annoying)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is your literal enum and map you don't need that map. Use `SomeEnum.first.name` to get the string.

If the strings are different. I would use a different approach. When using [Dart 2.17.0](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-17-b216bfc80c5d) or higher you can use enhanced enums and simple add methods to enums like this for example

```
enum SomeEnum { first, second;
  String getString() {
    switch (this) {
      case SomeEnum.first: return "first string";
      case SomeEnum.second: return "second string";
    }
  }

  int toInt() {
    switch (this) {
      case SomeEnum.first: return 1;
      case SomeEnum.second: return 2;
    }
  }
}
```

And then use `Some.first.getString()` wherever you need. Or `Some.first.toInt()` to get ints

For lower Dart versions you can write an extension instead and use it in the same way:

```
extension SomeEnumExtension on SomeEnum {
  String getString() {
    switch (this) {
      case SomeEnum.first: return "first string";
      case SomeEnum.second: return "second string";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as `Colors` class instead of enum:

```dart
abstract final class Colors {
  static const Color transparent = Color(0x00000000);
}
```